# What may cause EnumProcesses() to fail?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, winapi

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682629(v=vs.85).aspx) states:

> If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error
>   information, call GetLastError.

But it doesn't give any example how the function could possibly fail.

For unit testing I need to reliably create a situation that makes `EnumProcesses()` fail.

Comment: For unit testing, you should probably have a way of stubbing out the method of getting processes.

Comment: For managed code, there used to be Moles/Pex (now Microsoft Fakes), to provide replacements for system services, to exhibit reproducible behavior. I'm not aware of any such framework for native code, though, but I'd invest time researching the availability of those.

Comment: Every winapi function can fail.  There are no exception specifications.  It is almost never anything good, and certainly won't be for EnumProcesses, and testing whether the app successfully terminates with an exception is all that is required.

Comment: @HansPassant Sure, but the question is how to create a condition that makes `EnumProcesses` fail?

Comment: You'll have to do unspeakable things to the OS.  Do focus on *how* it reports failure, all you need is a *false* return value.  Something that #ifdef can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like most functions, it can fail if you pass it invalid parameters. In this case that means a smaller PID array than the size you tell it or a NULL pointer for the received count. It is a bit risky to do this on purpose because you don't know if the function uses SEH to protect against this or if it will just crash.

Internally the function has to allocate some memory before calling into NTDLL to get the process information and this can cause the function to fail if there is not enough memory available.

You should call EnumProcesses in a helper function to abstract away the memory/retry details anyway and that would be a good place to simulate failures when needed.

If you absolutely need the function itself to fail you could hook it with something like Microsoft Detours or IAT hooking...

Comment: I had hope that this could be done by simply removing process privileges or something similar that would change environmental conditions for `EnumProcesses` to make it fail. `NULL` for the received count causes the function to fail, but as you wrote, it could also just crash (if not now, then maybe in a future Windows version). "Simulating" failure would require a different code path for testing compared to release code (some #ifdef as @HansPassant suggested), so I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: But you should already have a helper function wrapping EnumProcesses so you don't need to deal with retrying etc. directly in your main code IMHO.

Comment: Yes I have. But within that wrapper I still have to either #ifdef (different code path) or add a parameter to simulate failure, don't I?

Comment: @zett42 - `EnumProcesses` ( `ZwQuerySystemInformation` with `SystemProcessInformation`) not fail even if you have no any privileges/sids in token. even after call `ZwImpersonateAnonymousToken` it not fail. only if you hook this api. however for hook api in own image not need detour or iat hoking. can be done more simply

Comment: @zett42 Yes you need #ifdef or check a environment variable to know when to simulate the failure but that would be true if you could hook or change EnumProcesses in other ways as well.

Comment: @RbMm Can you explain how to do API hooking without detour or IAT or give a link? Thanks.

Comment: @zett42 - all imported functions called via pointer variable. in case `K32EnumProcesses` this is `__imp_K32EnumProcesses` for not x86 and `__imp__K32EnumProcesses@12` for x86. so all what we need - declare this variable as `extern "C"
{
 extern PVOID __imp_K32EnumProcesses;
}` and modify it. for x86 we can not direct (in c++ code) declare name `PVOID __imp__K32EnumProcesses@12` but we can use `#pragma comment(linker, "/alternatename:___imp_K32EnumProcesses=__imp__K32EnumProcesses@12")` . full code [example](https://pastebin.com/NMZe7BDD)

Comment: @zett42 - so when you declare some api with `DECLSPEC_IMPORT` linker create named variable for this api and you can access it by name. say if you declare `extern "C" extern BOOL (*__imp_K32EnumProcesses)(DWORD*,DWORD,DWORD*);` the call `__imp_K32EnumProcesses(*);` and `K32EnumProcesses(*);` produce absolute the same binary code. one to one. by fact this same as when we declare function variable and initialize it by `GetProcAddress` and use this variable for call api. only in case imported functions linker for you call `GetProcAddress`

Comment: may assume that linker do `*(void**)&__imp_K32EnumProcesses=GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32"), "K32EnumProcesses");` for you. and calls `__imp_K32EnumProcesses()` vs `K32EnumProcesses()`  only different source syntax. in binary level no any different. code will be absolute identical for this 2 forms. and of course i get not x86 names for simply

Comment: I've decided to go with hooking as this allows me to keep the testee free of test code. For IAT hooking I already had working code for which I have created a RAII wrapper that allows me to temporarily hook an API by inserting a single line of code at the beginning of the test code. I like the solution of @RbMm for its simplicity but it seems to be compiler-dependend? Also I couldn't write a RAII wrapper because of the required #pragma for x86.

Comment: @zett42 - this not depend from compiler. you can note that `__imp_K32EnumProcesses` or `__imp__K32EnumProcesses@12` is exactly match to names in `kernel32.lib`. when we call some `function` marked as *dllimport* - compiler generate variable with name `__imp_function` (or `__imp__function@N` for x86). and than linker search exactly this name in obj/lib files. if not found - will be well known error - unresolved external symbol `__imp_function`. so names not compiler depended but must be exactly matched (symbol to symbol) to name in lib from sdk/wdk

Comment: also we can use `__pragma` instead of `#pragma` this let use macros inside `__pragma` and even `#define SOMENAME __pragma
SOMENAME(comment(linker, "/alternatename:***"))`