# Hiding dependency injection while unit testing shared library

Tags: c++, unit-testing, winapi, dependency-injection, information-hiding

After learning the importance of having automated testing in a codebase, I'm currently trying to add unit testing to my own fairly large C++ codebase.

The codebase I'm working on is a shared library. I think I understand how to deal with the numerous system calls I need to make; hide a lot of them behind interfaces and use dependency injection. The problem is, I don't want client code that is using the library to see the dependency injection, since that's only a requirement to make the library code unit testable.

For example, take this line of code:

```
TextBox* textBox = new TextBox();
```

The `TextBox` class contains code that makes multiple calls to Win32 API functions, such as the Clipboard. If I understand correctly, I need to do this in order to have the appropriate unit tests for the `TextBox` class:

```
TextBox* textbox = new TextBox(IClipboardApi* clipboard);
```

The problem is, if someone is using this library, I don't think they should have to provide a real clipboard instance. I could take advantage of default values:

```
TextBox* textbox = new TextBox(IClipobardApi* clipboard = CreateClipboardInstance());
```

But I don't know if this is the right way to go about it either.

I'm still very new to unit testing, and much of my library code was written before I learned about unit testing. It's completely possible this class is just not written well. If the class is written well enough, how could I go about hiding implementation details like this from clients? If the class isn't written properly, what might be a better design?

Comment: I would like to point two things: 1) it is suspicious that text box deals with clipboard, most likely it contains some data handling logic that shouldn't be present in UI component 2) if you are writing interfaces and introducing DI just to write unit tests you are doing something wrong

Comment: As pointed out by VTT, this looks like a poor separation of concerns. A `TextBox` should only deal with behavior of that particular control. If indeed it needs to interact with the clipboard, it can internally access the clipboard API's static interface. A clipboard API can be implemented completely stateless. There is not ever a reason to keep a clipboard object around (it wouldn't have to store any data anyway). You should probably ask about design issues at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @VTT If I want a TextBox to have copy/paste capability, I'm not sure how to not have clipboard accessing code in it. Do you have any suggestions?
@IInspectable The clipboard API is completely static. That theoretical `IClipboardApi` construct would only exist due to Unit Testing, and a `ClipboardApi` object would just make calls the real static API. But if TextBox is being unit tested, should it be calling the system's clipboard code? What if, for whatever reason, clipboard calls were expensive?

Comment: An alternative would be to mock out the clipboard API functions using API hooking. RbMm has presented a very easy way to do so in the comments to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46569055/7571258) (beginning Oct 5 at 12:10). The advantage is that your actual code keeps clean because the hooking can be done solely from your test suite.

Comment: @zett42 Is that the standard way most people trying to Unit Test C++ code that needs to make many system calls would do? It seems very...hacky. It should be do-able (already found a library called SubHook that can probably do the heavy lifting). I just want to follow whatever the standard approach would be.

Comment: I don't think there is a standard way. Just use what best fits your project. I have used API hooking and found it to be reliable in testing scenarios. I try to avoid it and rather test with the real API, but this isn't always possible, for instance when testing for rare failure.